# db2 set incrementing values using insert statement

Tags: sql, database, insert, db2, increment

I have two tables:

```
MYTABLE1
ID   |Col1|Col2      |
--------------------- ....
64  |  50 |   7000   |



MYTABLE2
MY_ID |
-------
  64  | 
  87  |
```

and i need to insert like 10,000 rows to MYTABLE1 where ID=MY_ID Col1=50 ant Col2 increments each time the row is inserted  so MYTABLE1 would look like that:

```
ID   |Col1|Col2      |
--------------------- ....
64  |  50 |   7000   |
87  |  50 |   7001   |
```

I have found similar solution here: [insert thousands of rows in DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746766/insert-thousands-of-rows-in-db2)

but i still cant figure out how to load all the IDs from MYTABLE2

Please help,
Thank You for Your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
insert into MYTABLE1 (id, col1, col2)
select my_id, 50 col1, col2 + row_number() over(order by my_id) from
(
    select MY_ID, m.col2
    from MYTABLE2 t2, (select max(col2) as col2 from MYTABLE1) m
) t2
-- if you don't want to insert IDs which already exist in MYTABLE1
where not exists (select 1 from MYTABLE1 t1 where t1.ID = t2.MY_ID);
```

Comment: `Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-206, SQLSTATE=42703, SQLERRMC=M.COL2, DRIVER=3.63.75
SQLState:  42703
ErrorCode: -206`

Comment: @JulioBordeaux I've added AS in this statement: "select max(col2) as col2". It's the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I think it could be something with "m"

Comment: @JulioBordeaux It's just a subquery alias

Comment: Woooh, it worked, when i tried `(select max(col2) as col2 from MYTABLE1) AS m`. Thanks alot, Mate! :)